# Nginx + laravel + Vue SPA returns index.php for all files except for the index

Tags: nginx, debian

I've been trying to get a simple Vue SPA working on my server but for some reason, the index page is the only one that gets processed by laravel and the style and javascript files are replaced by the index.php.

The web routes are simple, they just render the view:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('main');
});
```

And the NGINX configuration is also standard:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80;
    charset utf-8;

    root /home/gkovalechyn/gkovalechyn.net/public;
    index index.php index.html;

    server_name gkovalechyn.net www.gkovalechyn.net;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php /index.html;
        autoindex off;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known/ {
      root /home/gkovalechyn/gkovalechyn.net/.well-known;
      allow all;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/gkovalechyn.net/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/gkovalechyn.net/error.log;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/gkovalechyn.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/gkovalechyn.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


#     Redirect non-https traffic to https
     if ($scheme != "https") {
         return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
     } # managed by Certbot

}
```

And the view itself is just the headers and scripts:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1">

        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <title>gkovalechyn.net</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <router-view></router-view>
        </div>
    </body>

    <script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
</html>
```

Now, what happes is that those 2 asset links (js/app.js and css/app.css) do get their proper links (gkovalechyn.net/css/app.css and gkovalechyn.net/js/app.js).

However, if I try to access any of those 2 links they are always the public/index.php file.

Edit:
Files on the server:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZo1Z.png)

Comment: What is the filesystem path to the missing file?

Comment: @MichaelHampton The full paths would be:
/home/gkovalechyn/gkovalechyn.net/public/css/app.css
/home/gkovalechyn/gkovalechyn.net/public/js/app.js

But the files aren't really missing, they are there, but for some reason the server always returns the index.php file. I've added a picture of the files on the server.

Comment: That path seems to match your document root. Have you checked the permissions?

Comment: I changed ownership of the files to the NGINX user and group and it served the files properly. I changed it back to me and it is still working?  

I have no idea why it is working now and it wasn't before but thank you so much, I lost way too many hours trying to figure this out.